# Applications Session Timeout at IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, timeout

I have two applications hosted at IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 Server R2. One application is hosting at .net framework 4.0 and other on framework 2.0. Both have **Integrated** and **Classic** values for **Managed Pipeline Mode** property of Application Pool.
Issue is, at client machine only one application is login at a time, if I login to 1st application 2nd gone to session timeout and vice verse.
Please help and suggest which configuration is require at IIS end.